# When i make a call to a soap WS via WCF i get a null response

Tags: wcf, web-services, soap

Im trying to create a WCF consumer of a soap webservice.

I have created the webservice schema which in the request passes a string argument and gets back a string response, however when i call the service i get back a null response.

Ive looked at the TCP trace of whats going on and everything looks correct, i perform a post and get back an HTTP 200 response with the soap XML contained within.

Ive also tried the same thing using a WebReference and that works as expected (With the same request/200 response pattern), so im kinda stumped.

Is there a way i can plug into WCF to see why it thinks its getting no response or is there some other path i can go down to debug this?

Thanks

Comment: You can turn on WCF [tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) and [message logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx) but this looks more like WCF is not able deserialize your response. How did you make your client? Are you sure that namespaces and element names in message are correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what the issue was with this, I needed to decorate the Contract with the following to allow it to work out how to interpret the soap response

```
    [XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(Use = OperationFormatUse.Encoded)]
    [return: MessageParameterAttribute(Name = "MySoapReturnName")]
```